# Underscore Naming Convention in Objective-C System Macros

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, macros

I'm curious about the naming convention in Objective-C macros. For example, the following code is standard in every project's pre-compiled header file (.pch file)

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Why is __IPHONE_5_0 prefixed by 2 underscores and __OBJC__ both prefixed and postfixed by 2 underscores? Prefixed underscores usually indicate system stuff that the programmer shouldn't touch. But what about postfixed underscores? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of research and I found this snippet in [Apple's "Coding Guidelines for Cocoa"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1003095):

> Note that macros defined by the compiler have leading and trailing
>   double underscore characters. For example: `__MACH__`

Comment: nice tidbit! so how about macros with only 2 leading underscores but no trailing underscores such as in the code sample above? they are some other miscellaneous non-compiler-generated system stuff? this is an ambitious question, but is there a list or guide to explain a lot of these system guts we often see (and I usually glaze over)?